# Spring Security AOP Error

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have created a simple spring user application. I am using Tomcat for deployment. This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>ContactSync</display-name>
    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/user/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping> -->
</web-app>
```

my spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/user/denied.do" >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/login.do" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- Not using admin role right now -->
        <!-- <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/> -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/user/common.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>

        <security:form-login
                login-page="/user/login.do" 
                authentication-failure-url="/user/login.do?error=true" 
                default-target-url="/user/common.do"/>

        <security:logout 
                invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/user/login.do" 
                logout-url="/user/logout.do"/>


 </security:http>

 <security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
    <security:user-service>
        <security:user name="abcd" password="abcd" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

My LIbraries are:

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar
commons-collections-3.1.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.5.6.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
gson-2.2.1.jar
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.5.1-Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.2.0.Final.jar
j2ee.jar
javassist-3.4.GA.jar
javax.persistence-2.0.2.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.5.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar
slf4j-simple-1.5.6.jar
spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-acl-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-cas-client-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-cas-client-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-ldap-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-openid-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-openid-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.0.1.RELEASE.war
spring-security-samples-tutorial-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
standard-1.1.2.jar
yuicompressor-2.4.8pre.jar
```

I am getting 404 error when trying to access login file. However i am able to access welcome file. Can anybody help me on this.

```
Error:

HTTP Status 404 - /Learning/WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp

type Status report

message /Learning/WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp

description The requested resource (/Learning/WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp) is not available.
```

My LoginLogout Controller:

```
package com.contact.test.web;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@RequestMapping("/user")
@Controller
public class LoginLogoutController{

     @RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getLoginPage(@RequestParam(value="error", required=false) boolean error, 
       ModelMap model) {

      // Add an error message to the model if login is unsuccessful
      // The 'error' parameter is set to true based on the when the authentication has failed. 
      // We declared this under the authentication-failure-url attribute inside the spring-security.xml
      /* See below:
       <form-login 
        login-page="/user/login" 
        authentication-failure-url="/user/login?error=true" 
        default-target-url="/user/common"/>*/

      if (error == true) {
       // Assign an error message
       model.put("error", "You have entered an invalid username or password!");
      } else {
       model.put("error", "");
      }
      // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp
      return "loginpage";
     }

    /**
      * Handles and retrieves the denied JSP page. This is shown whenever a regular user
      * tries to access an admin only page.
      * 
      * @return the name of the JSP page
      */
     @RequestMapping(value = "/denied.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String getDeniedPage() {

      // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/deniedpage.jsp
      return "deniedpage";
     }
}
```

Structure of project is:

```
/Learning/WebContent
/Learning/WebContent/META-INF
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/adminpage.jsp
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/commonpage.jsp
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/deniedpage.jsp
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/loginpage.jsp
/Learning/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/userForm.jsp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-sources.jar
```

It does not contain any compiled java classes. You need to include:

```
spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Unrelated to this issue: You also need all of the required dependencies mentioned in the [spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE.pom.xml](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/3.0.1.RELEASE/spring-aop-3.0.1.RELEASE.pom)

Comment: thanks...now i am able to access welcome page but unable to access login page...please see the error above...

Comment: Any resources contained in the WEB-INF folder are not directly accessible from a browser. You should move them to WebContent Folder.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to put also such libs to your buildpath:

```
asm-3.3.1.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.12.jar
aspectjtools-1.6.12.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.12.jar
```

Versions may differ, I just copied names of the libs from my project.